# How to set meta data in the play framework?

Tags: metadata, playframework-1.x

I am using the play framework 1.2.6 and can't seem to find a handy way to set the meta data description in the html pages. To set the title there is this:

```
#{set title:'This is the title' /}
```

which generates

```
<title>This is the title</title>
```

Is there anything similar which would generate this:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the description">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was much easier than I thought. I just modified this part of code in header.html:

```
<meta name="description" content="#{get 'description' /}">
```

And then in a page that extends header.html:

```
#{set description:'This is the description' /}
```